# Mocking a simple method inside Service class in Grails

Tags: unit-testing, grails

i was trying to mock a method (passwordComplexityCheck) which is inside UserService class.

Below is what i did for mocking in my test class

```
def userService
controller.userService=new UserService()

controller.userService=[passwordComplexityCheck:{def k->
   return true
}]
```

But this is not working.

Below is the UserService class and the method.

```
class UserService {
   //required declaration 
   ........
   public boolean passwordComplexityCheck(String password) {

      log.debug("Enter(Method) - passwordComplexityCheck()")

      if (password != null && password.trim() != "") {
         if (password.length() < grailsApplication.config.user.password.min.length) {
            return false
         }
         if (password == password.toLowerCase()) {
            return false
         }
         if (password == password.toUpperCase()) {
            return false
         }
         if (password.grep(~/\d+/).size == 0) {
            return false
         }
      } else {
         return false
      }
      return true
   }
}
```

I just need to mock this in a way that it can return either return true or false. Since the method has an argument, mocking will be  different? What is the general way for mocking methods in services?

Comment: In what way is this not working? are you getting an error? or just not getting the behaviour you expect? Knowing what exception or behaviour you are seeing will help track down the problem.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. Error was occuring due to the log in UserService class. Could you please advise how to mock the log in service class?

Comment: log.debug("Enter(Method) - passwordComplexityCheck()")

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: log for class: com.merckserono.ecko.data.UserService
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:49)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:86)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
com.merckserono.ecko.data.UserService.passwordComplexityCheck(UserService.groovy:290)com.merckserono.ecko.data.UserService$passwordComplexityCheck.call(Unknown Source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that the in-built logging in Grails works during testing you will have to mock the logging functionality. To do this you want to include the code below in your test class. The best place is in the setUp() method before any of your code gets called.

`mockLogging(UserService, true)`

See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html#mockLogging%28java.lang.Class,%20boolean%29

Comment: in my config file , i have a value "user.password.min.length = 6" and i tried to mock this as "mockConfig(user.password.min.length). But this is showing null pointer exception. This value was taken as grailsApplication.config.user.password.min.length in the code. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure about that one, mate. I'd check the docs for mockConfig() and ask a new question here if you don't find your answer. Good luck.